# By the definition of a derivative, find the first derivative of $\sin^{-1} x$

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

By the definition of a derivative, find the first derivative of $\sin^{-1} x$?
Could anyone help me please

Comment: do you mean $$\arcsin(x)$$?

Comment: yes @Dr.SonnhardGraubner

Comment: How much do you have to work with? Do you know about implicit differentiation?

Comment: yes I know @UmbertoP.